# generate random session IDs OpenTok

Tags: php, session, heroku, opentok

In my iOS app I am using TokBox to implement a private video chat feature. 
I need to create a random session ID for each private chat, using the Server SDK API and I am having hard time understanding how to do it.

I successfully completed all the steps listed in the documentation “**learning-opentok-php**” available on the **opentok github** page.
I linked my OpenTok app with Heroku and configured the “web/index.php” to show me the static “SESSION_ID” and “TOKEN_ID” on my browser.

As explained in the documentation the “Sample App” uses a single session ID and does not generate a new session ID for each call. Please can someone provide some examples or advice on how to configure my app to generate each time a different Session ID?.

Comment: Read this :https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php#1-generate-a-session-and-token

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The lines of code you mentioned in the article are stored in a file called index.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
// If a sessionId has already been created, retrieve it from the cache
$sessionId = $app->cache->getOrCreate('sessionId', array(), function() use ($app) {
    // If the sessionId hasn't been created, create it now and store it
    $session = $app->opentok->createSession();
    return $session->getSessionId();
});
// Generate a fresh token for this client
$token = $app->opentok->generateToken($sessionId);
$app->render('helloworld.php', array(
    'apiKey' => $app->apiKey,
    'sessionId' => $sessionId,
    'token' => $token
));
```

});
try this code

send request on server get every time new sessionId.